# How to run Edwin editor in console mode

Tags: mit-scheme, edwin

I am an absolute Lisp / Scheme beginner, now trying to self-teach by reading Simply Scheme from page 1. I downloaded MIT/GNU Scheme with builtin Edwin editor. I would like to run Edwin in console mode under iTerm rather than in its default X11/XQuartz mode which takes more time to start and has eyes-hurting bitmap font display.

I found out the page [Starting Edwin](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.5/OLD/7.5.5/doc-html/user_8.html) which lists a `(console)` variable under `variable+: create-editor-args`, I think it must be what I need, but I do not know exactly what to type under shell prompt to invoke it. I beg your pardon for asking such a stupid question.

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to open Edwin in a console](https://www.monolune.com/how-to-open-edwin-in-a-console/)

Answer (score 2):

One of my Facebook friends told me that there are two ways of running Edwin in console mode:

1. `$ DISPLAY= scheme -edit` Note that the equal sign should be followed by a space character which is to assign an empty value to `DISPLAY` environment variable.
2. `$ scheme`, then in scheme REPL, `(edit 'console)`

Either way will go into Edwin console mode, but Edwin 3.116 (builtin with MIT/GNU Scheme Release 9.2 x86-64 for Mac OS X) will show an error message

```
Evaluation error:
The primitive xterm-y-size is not implemented in this version of Scheme.
```

And it asks if the user wants to `Start debugger (y or n)?`, I just press n to skip it.

Answer (score 1):

To run Edwin in the terminal:

```
mit-scheme --eval "(edwin 'console)"
```